# How do I get contents of new HTML5 elements using DOMDocument?

Tags: dom, domdocument

How do I retrieve info from new HTML5 elements (like article, figure, meta tags within other elements), using PHP DOMDocument.

Answer (score 1):

yiou can see here https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php

It works very well.